# Telebot против aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Всем привет. Поведаю вам свою прискорбную ситуацию.

Два месяца назад появилась идея написания бота для телеграмма на языке Python. По сей день усиленно занимался реализацией своих мысли и желания, но лишь под конец стал понимать, что библиотека telebot достаточно плохо показывает себя в продакшене, так как bot.polling() - это очень больная тема для всех, кто хоть раз пытался залить своего бота на сервер, плюс ко всему, при большом количестве пользователей бот ведет себя достаточно медленно.

И под конец, когда все было готово, будто бы оказался у разбитого корыта, ведь нормально запустить бота и все время держать его онлайн - тот еще велосипед, который разработчики telegram никак не хотят изобретать. Вследствие этого возникает очень резонный вопрос: насколько сложно переписать бота с библиотеки telebot на библиотеку aiogram?

Можно ли будет просто заменить def на async def и добавить await перед каждым отправлением сообщения? В своем боте использовал большой функционал библиотеки telebot (inline/reply keyboards, send_media_group, delete_message, базы данных и так далее)

Надеюсь, найдутся те, кто сталкивался с такой же проблемой)

Comment: Та же ситуация, решил просто- беру массив кода кидаю в gpt и говорю перепиши части кода telebot на aiogram.

Answer (score 2):

Твоя проблема, насколько я могу понять, в том, что ты не можешь пустить бота в продакшен с пуллингом. Но это и не удивительно, пуллинг для этого не предназначен, тебе нужен вебхук. Тогда бот не будет отваливаться постоянно. В репо telebot есть пример вебхука на flask. После можешь сделать деплой на хероку, если проект небольшой, то будет бесплатно(500ч).

Aiogram следует использовать, при большой нагрузке на бота, он работает быстрее. И если нужен асинхрон, то это твой выбор. В иных случаях не вижу смысла.

Но если все таки нужно, то это вполне можно сделать используя документацию к aiogram

Скорее всего я уже опоздал с ответом, но надеюсь, что хоть чем то помог тебе)

Answer (score 0):

Да, сложно. Не мучайся с этим, просто возьми идею своего бота и полностью **С НУЛЯ** препиши его на **aiogram**. Так ты больше освоишь эту библиотеку и будет меньше путаниц как в коде, так и в голове.

Answer (score 0):

На счёт poling проблема решается через [продление сессии](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/1058#issuecomment-761699869).

```
apihelper.SESSION_TIME_TO_LIVE = 5 * 60
```

Для работы с большим количеством пользователей попробуй [асинхронную версию telebot.](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/tree/master/examples/asynchronous_telebot)

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже возник этот вопрос. Я решил немного поизучать aiogram и решить что делать дальше. По итогу я просто заменил def на async def и добавить await перед каждым отправлением сообщения. Пришлось помучится с некоторыми нюансами моего бота, и через 2 дня мой асинхронный тбот был готов!

Главное заранее поизучать aiogram, и всё получится)